# What's the best way to access a value immediately, when it's come from the server?

Tags: objective-c, oop

I have server side tables 'user' and 'user_currency'.

In my front end iOS application, I desire to be able to retrieve the user's current currency (in-app currency) amount in various area of the application. For example, it will be displayed on nearly every view in the application, showing them how much they currently have. It will also be used when performing an action that requires currency.

How should this best be set up?

A) Let's say we only have a method called fetchUserCurrencyWithCompletion. This method will fetch the data from the server asynchronously, and then the caller will need to provide some code in the completion block on what to do with it. There is a problem with this. If every view in the app is displaying the user's currency amount, to have to wait until the asynch is done, would cause some 'screen/view flicker' everytime, as the view would load first and then some time later the currency would display.

B) Implement a cache in fetchUserCurrencyWithCompletion. instead of (void), make it (NSNumber *)fetchUserCurrencyWithCompletion. The immediate return NSNumber value will contain the cached currency value. Then once again, after the asynch fetch is run, the callers completion code will be run, and they can update their usage of currency accordingly. This will only cause screen flicker for the currency amount being displayed, when the fetchedResult is different from the cache. Which shouldn't be often. If there was another client using this server, say a website, then the user on the website could spend 5 currency, and the iOS app would originally pull in 15 currency total via the cache, and then update to 10 once the server fetch is complete. But I have no other client. Just the iOS app. So this should never happen.

Then, when an area of the application is going to perform an action that requires currency, it would use fetchUserCurrencyWithCompletion, and wait for completion to get the server result to ensure that the user had enough currency to perform the action.

Is this a good way of designing this? I'm still quite new, and not sure the best way of doing this.

Comment: There is a technique I've seen used once that worked amazingly well, for being so low-tech.  Basically, the server is set up so that you can issue a request to it that won't return unless something changes.  So you issue a request (with a long timeout) and then go about your business.  If the request ever completes then it asynchronously updates whatever needs updating.  If the request times out it simply reissues itself.  It does tie up a server port, though, and other resources.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you proposed in your B point seems very good but I would also suggest that you do the following:

1. Implement the cache as you proposed
2. Store this cache in a local file on the iPhone
3. Always let your method returns the local cache unless the file wasn't found
4. Now to update the local currency value from the server and since you said it doesn't always happen so simply don't send too many requests to your server, just use APNS (Apple Push Notification Services), starting with iOS 7, you can send push data without a notification so whenever the currency is updated, you can send a push data to the iPhone and your app simply updates the local value